# How to update the defnition of a function such that the default value set to a state variable is always up to date

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component like below.

When the function `buttonOnClick` is defined, I pass `inputFormData` as the default value to argument `formdata`. However, `inputFormData` in the function does not get updated when `inputFormData` is updated with `setInputFormData`. How to acomplish this?

I tried wrapping the whole function inside `useEffect` but that does not work for me because I need this function outside of `useEffect`. In fact this function is called by another component which does not have access to `inputFormData` and hence it is necessary to update the value in the function.

```
import {isObjectEmpty} from './utils'

const App= React.memo((props) => {
const [inputFormData, setInputFormData] = useState({});

function buttonOnClick(eventId, data, formdata = inputFormData) {    
   if (isObjectEmpty(formdata)) {
                    setShowFillFormModal(true);
                    return;
                  }
    }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span> Rendered </span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *probably* related with a fact that the *default* value assignment (`formdata = inputFormData`) works **only** if the argument is `undefined` (and in your case, it's an *empty object* `{}`).

The part `formdata = inputFormData` is not the best solution and personally I'd remove it completely since it's better to have a single source of truth and currently you have two of them (state and argument).

However if you insist, I'd do something like:

```
function buttonOnClick(eventId, data, formdata) {   
   const finalData = isEmpty(formData) ? inputFormData : formData;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @kind user. However, my main concern is that from where this function is being called, it is called just ` buttonOnClick("view-details")` where "view-details" is an `eventId` and I am not able to access `formData` or `inputFormData` inside this function. Hence I wanted a method to keep the variable `formdata `updated to `inputFormData` at all times

Comment: @moys `formData` is an argument and it's value depends on how and where you call it. Please try the solution I proposed and let me know on the results.